# GDB gets messed up after leaving TUI

Tags: gdb

I am working with gdb and I entered then left tui. after leaving however the console environment became unusable. The phenomenon is that whether a newline is printed it seems that \r is not making the second line start where the first ends like this:

```
(gdb) some command
                  some output
                             (gdb) some other command
                                                     some other output
                                                                      (gdb)
```

This is not solved by restarting gdb. I am on linux so I am not sure why \r would be needed or what even causes this. I am also under tmux if that makes a difference. Resizing the current window returns the prompt to the start but does not fix the issue.

Note: Restarting the zsh session fixed the issue but I still would like to know what happens.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/39771932/72178.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know how to search it